# Rails pass radio button params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hey guys I am a newbie so go easy on me.

I am trying to figure out how to pass to the controller the radio button choice. It is NOT part of the model. Here is the code:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:remove, "yes") %>
<%= label_tag(:yes_delete, "yes, delete the order") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:remove, "no") %>
<%= label_tag(:no_dont_delete, "No, do not delete the order") %>

<h4 class="row"><td><%= link_to 'Delete', payment_path(:id => @payment.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td></h4>
```

When I click delete all here is what the params look like:

```
Parameters: "authenticity_token"=>"lfFsfN04ajhIpYI13bwhmGtLtQIdRUkaClPsBBP12SSZwDEnsIslOqH3yptGvWUF620bEYhPBgbD7sLYV2cA7Q==", "id"=>"175"}
```

Thank for the help.

Comment: You're missing some code before `@payment.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` can handle that easily.

```
<%= form_for @payment, method: :delete do |f| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:remove, "yes") %>
    <%= label_tag(:yes_delete, "yes, delete the order") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:remove, "no") %>
    <%= label_tag(:no_dont_delete, "No, do not delete the order") %>

    <h4 class="row"><td><%= f.submit 'Delete', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td></h4>
<% end %>
```

The `post` parameters received by the server:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KoCb84m88ptGUPbY9eofUMjpGLGmpKfUwBxB2t+Fv+QABr6lWnWpsEuJQ/quOJN3g6Zm+DZy2JTdVokjMQxLvQ==", "remove"=>"yes", "commit"=>"Delete", "id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. For some reason I thought each element in the form had to be associated to the model. Again i am a newbie. Thanks again Jason